# Selection of dropdownlist in Bootstrap modal causes reload

Tags: jquery, webforms, updatepanel, bootstrap-modal, reload

I have webforms application which is using bootstrap and it has updatepanel inside modal popup. Popup has dropdownlists. There is also some jQuery in the soup.

When I run this application on local workstation (Windows 7/10), it is functioning just fine: the whole page is loaded only once. But if I run this application on Windows 7 Enterprise, modal popup is closed and whole page is reloaded each time selections are made on dropdownlists.

This occurs with both IE and Google Chrome.

UPDATE:
I installed my app on Windows Server 2012R2 also and issue occurred in that case too. I tested the site both locally and remotely also, but no difference.

Related issues:

[Bootstrap modal closes when dropdownlist inside fires selected index changed event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726980/bootstrap-modal-closes-when-dropdownlist-inside-fires-selected-index-changed-eve)